# where is the privatekey and transation store in chrome file using metamask extension

Tags: ethereum, metamask

i want to know where is the privatekey and transation store in google chrome file  using metamask extension. can you help me? it is in /Users/jackson/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions???

Answer (score 18):

Metamask stores your private keys using your browser's data store. The source code of Metamask is auditable, like Parity and MyEtherWallet, by downloading from a repository (which you can then be more assured that the program you are running has indeed been looked at by other people -- unless someone is man-in-the-middle attacking you) or by unpacking the Chromium extension you downloaded.

Using Chrome on a Mac, your data is stored in ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Defaults/Extensions.

To find which directory it is in, you can do a search `grep -rw 'metamask' *`. This will search for all instances of the word "matamask" within these folders.

Comment: thank you! it is help me! i also want to know the privateKey is store  in ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Defaults/Extensions  or %LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage ?  i can't find which file is,thank you !

Comment: Great! Feel free to approve my answer and give me an upvote so other people with this question will know the answer!

Comment: the upvode need 15 reputation but i only have 11. i will upvode you in  the future.thank you!

Comment: TIP: The flag `-l` (lowercase L) in grep return just the filename, so `grep -rwl 'metamask' .` will give a quieter output.